# Casual vs Cavalier vs Nonchalant vs Indifferent

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm having a hard time deciding if *casual*, *cavalier*, *nonchalant* and *indifferent* could be used interchangeably in such contexts as the following:They (except the last one) are examples cited in Merriam Webster's either Unabridged Dictionary or Citations.

**Cavalier**

He has a *cavalier* disregard for the rights of others.

People are *cavalier* with facts, let alone with opinions.P. 9 JOURNALISM MADE SIMPLE David Wainwright W. H. Allen, London 072 W13j 1972

**Nonchalant**

She faced the crowd with the *nonchalant* ease of an experienced speaker.

The team may have been somewhat *nonchalant* at the beginning of the season, but they now know that they need to work hard.

**Casual**

were *casual* with their hogs and let them run through the peanut fields after harvest.  P. 62 Roon Frost GOURMET Vol. XLI No. 4 April, 1981

**Indifferent**

How to remain *indifferent* to one's pleas both in times of trouble and in times of joy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cavalier involves a lack of concern for someone or for some principle.

Nonchalant  involves an apparent lack concern for some difficulty or risk.

Casual involves a lack of concern for formality or regulation or order or rule.

Indifferent involves an utter lack of concern or total uninvolvement.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem to me that they are all variations on the concept of general indifference.

Cavalier indicates a spiteful or mocking indifference.

Nonchalant suggests a subtle attitude of indifference to avoid drawing notice or to appear unimpressed.

Casual would be a relaxed indifference or an unwillingness to exert effort beyond necessary